# Eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue does not follow the axis with the largest variance

Tags: python, pca

I have a simulated dataset created in Blender that represents a half cylinder.

[image]

I apply pca in order to find the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues. The eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue should follow the Z axis, which is the height of the cylinder and it actually does.

```
np.var(data, axis=0)
x     0.225168
y     0.057463
z    33.122499
dtype: float64
```

So, I am computing the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, I order them (maybe somewhere here is the issue) but when I plot them the eigenvector with the lowest eigenvalue follows the cylinder axis, with the highest variance. Also, when I am trying to project the 3d point cloud to the plane that is created from the two eigenvectors with the lowest eigenvalue (normally a circle would be created), it takes the wrong eigenvectors so it created a cylinder. This has to do with the selection of the eigenvectors with the lowest eigenvalues. I indeed select them correctly (so the code is correct), yet in reality they are not the correct vectors.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from r_pca import R_pca  # Ensure you have the r_pca library installed
from hyper_fit_with_lts import *
from cfg_fit_cylinder import *

def plot_vectors(data, eigvecs, eigenvals):
    colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
    # Create a 3D scatter plot of the centered data
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], label='Data', c='g', marker='x', alpha=0.1)

    # Plot eigenvectors as vectors
    for i in range(3): 
        vector = eigvecs[:, i]
        ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, vector[0], vector[1], vector[2], color=colors[i], label=f'Eigenvector {eigvecs[:, i]}, {eigenvals[i]}')

    ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()

data = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_POINT_CLOUD, header=None)
data.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']

rpca = R_pca(data.values) # RPCA
L, S = rpca.fit(max_iter=10_000)
column_means = np.mean(L, axis=0)
centered_L = L - column_means
cov_matrix = np.cov(centered_L, rowvar=False)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(cov_matrix)

print("Eigenvectors (Principal Components):")
print(eigenvectors)
print("\nEigenvalues")
print(eigenvalues)


centered_data = data - data.mean()
sorted_indices = np.argsort(-eigenvalues)
sorted_eigenvalues = sorted(eigenvalues, reverse=True)
sorted_eigenvectors = eigenvectors[:, sorted_indices]
plot_vectors(data.values, sorted_eigenvectors, sorted_eigenvalues)

smallest_components = sorted_eigenvectors[:, 1:] # Smallest eigenvectors (eigenvalues)

circle_projected_data = centered_data @ smallest_components
cylinder_2d_projection = sorted_eigenvectors[:, :2].T @ centered_data.T
cylinder_1d_projection = sorted_eigenvectors[:, 0].T @ centered_data.T
cylinder_height = np.ptp(cylinder_1d_projection)

circle_projected_data_without_centering = data @ smallest_components

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(circle_projected_data[0], circle_projected_data[1], color='r', label='Circle 2D in XY')
ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax1.set_title('Cycle 2D Projected Data')
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can see in the figure above, that the blue eigenvector which has the lowest eigenvalue  follows the cylinder axis.

NOTE: I have to mention that I am confused with the point cloud export from blender. I have picked up axis as Z and forward as Y but also forward as X.

Can someone spot the error?

Comment: What's the reason for using this R_pca library? If I use the sklearn PCA, and the dataset from your previous question, I can find the vector `[-7.23088957e-04,  1.00405101e-02, -9.99949331e-01]`. Code to find this vector: `sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components=1).fit(data).components_[0]`

Comment: I use it in order to exclude outliers based on this paper: https://isprs-archives.copernicus.org/articles/XLII-1-W1/63/2017/isprs-archives-XLII-1-W1-63-2017.pdf.

I am trying to produce good results in a simple dataset and afterwards in a more complicated

Comment: Got it. I can't find this library on PyPi - is this the correct library, or is it something else? https://github.com/dganguli/robust-pca/

Comment: This is the one! Also, I used simple PCA and again when I plot the point cloud along with the eigenvectors, the eigenvector with the smallest eigenvalue spans the cylinder axis.. I believe that I miss something fundamental or the dataset is not circular enough

Comment: Plotting the output of L and S, it seems like RPCA algorithm is putting all of the Z variance into S, so if you do PCA on the leftover part in L, then you will get a very low eigenvalue for the Z vector.

Comment: You are right. Robust PCA using L and S matrices is not the correct way of solving this problem. Instead I used DetMCD to grab the points that have the minimum covariance, so throw away the gross errors. Million thanks for the help